# How can I evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2} \ln x}{x^2 + 1}$ with the keyhole contour?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to evaluate $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2} \ln x}{x^2 + 1}$$ using the keyhole contour shown below. Let us define $f(z) = \frac{z^{1/2}(ln |z| + i \arg  z)}{z^2 + 1}$ with $\arg z \in (0, 2\pi)$.

[image]

Here, I have used the branch cut along the positive real axis. The integrals along the blue and black circles go to 0 by the ML bound. There are two simple poles at $\pm i$. The sum of the residues is given by $\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt 2}$ (verified by using a residue calculator on wolfram alpha).

Denote the endpoints of the green as $L$ and $R$ respectively. Evaluating $f(z)$ along the green line where $z = xe^{i \theta}$ and $\theta \approx 0$ gives us $\int_{L}^R \frac{x^{1/2} \ln x}{x^2 + 1}\,dx$ which is exactly the integral we want as $L \to 0, R \to \infty$.

Now evaluating along the red integral gives us $\int_{R}^L \frac{x^{1/2} e^{i \pi}(\ln x + i 2\pi)}{x^2 + 1}\,dx$, and since the red is in the reverse direction of the green, this is equivalent to

$$\int_{L}^R \frac{x^{1/2}\ln x}{x^2 + 1}\,dx + 2\pi i\int_{L}^R \frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 +1}\,dx.$$

This is now problematic, since I have the expression (in the limit)
$$2\pi i \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt 2} = 2I + 2\pi i \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2 + 1}\,dx$$

and I can't seem to get rid of the $i$ at all. How can I proceed with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is wolfram alpha is computing residues which are inconsistent with your branch cut. Computing the residue at $z = -i$ using the branch cut you defined, I get

$$\text{Res}_{z=-i}\left(\frac{\sqrt{z}\log(z)}{(z-i)(z+i)}\right) = -e^{\frac{3\pi}{4}i}\frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

Therefore, after summing the two residues together, we get

$$2\pi i\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}i\right) = 2I + 2\pi i\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+1}dx.$$

You can then separate real and imaginary parts to get the desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{I \equiv \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\,\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}
\,\dd x}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$

---

\begin{align}
& \mbox{Lets}\ \left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}{\cal F}\pars{\nu}\,\right\vert
_{\ds{\,\Re\pars{\nu} \in \pars{-1,1}}} \equiv \oint_{\cal C}\ \overbrace{{z^{\nu}\over z^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{\equiv \on{f}\pars{z,\nu}}}\
{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\quad
\substack{\mbox{where}\ \ds{\cal C}\ \mbox{is the}\\[1mm]
\ds{key\mbox{-}hole\ contour}\\[1mm] \mbox{in the original post.}}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Then,}\ {\cal F}\pars{\nu} =
\on{Res}\bracks{\on{f}\pars{z,\nu}, z = \expo{\pi\ic/2}} +
\on{Res}\bracks{\on{f}\pars{z,\nu}, z = \expo{3\pi\ic/2}}
\\[5mm] & \phantom{\mbox{Then,}\ {\cal F}\,\,\,} =
{\expo{\pi\nu\ic/2} \over 2\ic} + {\expo{3\pi\nu\ic/2} \over -2\ic} =
-\expo{\pi\nu\ic}\sin\pars{\pi\nu \over 2}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

---

Moreover,
\begin{align}
{\cal F}\pars{\nu} & = \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\nu}\ln\pars{x} \over
x^{2} + 1}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic} +
\int_{\infty}^{0}{x^{\nu}\expo{2\pi\nu\ic} \over x^{2} + 1}
{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{1 - \expo{2\pi\nu\ic}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\nu}\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}
{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
(\ref{1}) and (\ref{2}) lead to
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\nu} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x =
-2\pi\ic\,{\expo{\pi\nu\ic}\sin\pars{\pi\nu/2} \over 1 - \expo{2\pi\nu\ic}}
\\[5mm] & \implies
\color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/2}\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x} =
-2\pi\ic\,\lim_{\nu \to 1/2}\,\,\partiald{}{\nu}\bracks{{\expo{\pi\nu\ic}\sin\pars{\pi\nu/2} \over 1 - \expo{2\pi\nu\ic}}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\color{#44f}{{\root{2} \over 4}\,\pi^{2}}}
\approx 3.4894 \\ &
\end{align}